# How to manage a contact relation in database

Tags: sql, database, schema

I have to create a database schema to manager user contacts. I explain...

I have a simple **User** table with a primary key (named Id).

I have a **Contact** table having two foreign keys (SenderID to User, ReceiverID to User) constituting the primary key.

My problem is that if user A send a contact invitation to user B, we have the following entry :

Contact(A,B)

In this case, we can have an entry Contact(B,A) that is similar to other entry.

How can I manage this case ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two separate tables, one for pending requests `ContactRequests(SenderID, ReceiverID)`, and another for contact lists named `Contact(user_id,contact_id)`.

I would store all contact requests in `ContactRequests` like you did and upon request validation, I would create two entries in `Contact` like this: `Contact(A,B)` `Contact(B,A)`
And delete the pending request.
By doing so you are able to easily get a user contact list independently from who sent the request.

Googling for ["many to many relationship"](https://www.google.fr/?q=many%20to%20many%20relationship) could also help you design your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check for many to many relationship. However, I would like to avoid "duplicated" entries (Contact(A,B) and Contact(B,A)), but I don't know if it's possible with database constraints only or if I need to deal with it directly in my app source code.

Comment: If you don't want duplicate entries you could have only one entry per contact, (A,B) or (B,A), and then when you want to fetch A or B's contact list, use `WHERE user_id=xxx OR contact_id=xxx` but maybe such request would be slower